# Add required in html when some text on click

Tags: javascript, html

everyone.

i want to add required in my text box if a yes text onclick, and when i click the no and then required from text box is disappear. how can i do that ?

here is my code, what have i miss ?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yes").click(function(){
           //i dont have any idea here
        });
        $("#no").click(function(){
           //i dont have any idea here
        });
    });
    </script>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="school">
<a href="#" id="yes">yes</a>
<a href="#" id="no">no</a>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Try - `$(this).attr('required', true)`

Comment: Yes. Give your element another attribute just like @bos3 said

Comment: You can do inline like `<a href="#" id="yes" onclick="$(this).attr('required',true)">yes</a>
<a href="#" id="no" onclick="$(this).attr('required',false)">no</a>`

Comment: thanks @b0s3, its working now!, and very well thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code Add `id` to textbox.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="school" id="school">
<a href="#" id="yes">yes</a>
<a href="#" id="no">no</a>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript Code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yes").click(function(){
       $("#school").attr('required',true);
    });
    $("#no").click(function(){
        $("#school").attr('required',false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: `$("input[type=text]").prop('required',true);`
Your overall code will be

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yes").click(function(){
           $("input[type=text]").prop('required',true);
        });
        $("#no").click(function(){
           $("input[type=text]").prop('required',false);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yes").click(function(){
           $(this).prop('required',true);
        });
        $("#no").click(function(){
           $(this).prop('required',false);
        });
    });
```